# Can anyone help me with understanding ||w||

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am studying Machine Learning (SVMs), and I found this $||w||$ in front of me. I have not seen it again, and Google does not allow me to search for it. Does anyone knows what is $w$, what is $||w||$, how it is called, and why we need that?

Many thanks

Comment: ...the norm of w.

Comment: The (2) norm of the separating hyperplane `w`.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to cross validated. When asking questions, please take care that they are actually answerable: so if you ask about a specific symbol, it is probably best if you include some context. You can cite the relevant part the paper/book where you found it, and give a link to the full source. After all, everyone is free to define his own $w$...

Comment: Typically, $\|x\|$ denotes $\sqrt{x_1^2 + \dotsb + x_n^2}$, with $x = (x_1 \dotsc x_n)^\prime$.

Comment: thanks guys. So I have found that this is ||w|| = sqrt(w1^2+w2^2....wn^2). Is this right? But also what is vector w? and what it's relation with the hypeplane?

Comment: @cbeleites Thanks for your comment. That is the problem. It was just an equation at my professors lectures, while he had not explanation underneath about each symbol. That is the reason I needed to ask here...

Comment: @JohnSmith `w` *is* the hyperplane.

Comment: @JohnSmith: well, then put the equations the prof had where the $w$ appeared (I'd expect it to be the normal vector of the separating hyperplane, as Marc Claesen says). And maybe tell us that this was in a lecture.

Comment: @cbeleites He had a graph with points and a line separating them, and he wrote y(x) = w^Tx + w0. And at the graph he also had a line vertical with the hyperplane starting from the start of axes, which he said that it was the vector w, and in addition a point x with an y(x)/||w|| next to it. To be honest, I did not understand much of these things... And there is not any other explanation at the slides..

Comment: For similar questions, try e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Answer (score 1):

$\Vert w \Vert$ represents the norm of the vector $w$.

There are different norms that you can consider. When it is not said, it's often the euclidian norm, the norm 2:

$$\Vert w \Vert = \Vert w \Vert_2 = \sqrt{w_1^2 + \cdots + w_n^2}$$

Here are some other norms:

- norm 1: $$\Vert w \Vert_1 = |w_1| + \cdots + |w_n|$$
- norm $p$: $$\Vert w \Vert_p = \left( |w_1|^p + \cdots + |w_n|^p \right)^{1/p}$$
- infinite norm: $$\Vert w \Vert_\infty = \lim_{p \to \infty} \Vert w \Vert_p = max\left\{ |w_1| + \cdots + |w_n| \right\}$$

Here are more details on the Wikipedia page [Norm (Mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 0):

Right, one way to think of $w$ is as a vector representing a separating hyperplane.  However, in order to understand its usefulness, you better consider it a regularization value:  $||w||$  is a measure for the complexity of the model represented by the SVM.   The idea is to find a model that on one hand accurately models the training data, and on the other hand has a minimal complexity, because simple models tend to generalize better.  So the optimization term of the SVM has two components, with $||w||$ representing the complexity.